# Probability of selecting your name out of a bag

Tags: probability

If $N$ people write their name on a slip of paper and put them in a bag, then everyone draws one out at random, is there an equation to calculate the odds that $M$ people draw their name out?

Comment: Yes.  First choose which $M$ people picked their own names out.  Then for the remaining $N-M$ people, pick a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of their names.  This gives $!(N-M)\binom{N}{M}$ total ways they could do this.  Divide by $N!$ to get the probability.  (*If you specifically want odds instead of probability, just convert the probability into odds to finish.  If you don't, then you need to get out of the habit of calling it "odds" because the odds of something happening is NOT the same as the probability of it happening; they are related but different concepts*)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz for your response.  It occurred to me that I also failed to clarify whether I wanted you to respond in English or Russian.  Fortunately, I wanted English so I was able to understand your answer. Had I wanted Russian I would have had to use google translate which would have had a hard time with the math symbols.  If I had wanted Russian, I should probably get out of the habit of writing my questions in English since they are very different.  They are related, but not the same.

Comment: This site is primarily used by English speakers, so had you tried asking in Russian or asked for an answer in Russian you might have had worse luck in getting a response.  That being said, [these](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la) meta [posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/asking-questions-in-a-language-other-than-english) suggest that it isn't against the rules to do so.